# Cucumber Gherkin AmbigiousStepDefinition Issue

Tags: cucumber, gherkin

I am getting an AmbigiousStepDefinitionsException and I am not sure why I am getting thir error. How can I get around it?

```
      And I look for an apple in yellow basket with the following items
or
      And I look for an apple in basket with the following items


        @When("^I look for an? (apple|pear|grape) in (.*) basket with the following items:$")
        Public void findStoreItems(String fruit, Map<string,String> itemList)

        @When("^I look for an? (apple|pear|grape) in basket for the shop with the following items:$)
        Public void findColorItems(String fruit, String color, Map<string,String> itemList)
```

Comment: Are you sure the regex's you have put in the question are the same as your code?  If they are then I'm not sure why you would be getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

Use `--guess` while execution.

This will resolve the Ambiguous match error.

example:

```
cucumber path_to_file.feature --guess
```

Comment: While this will resolve the error, it might do it by picking an incorrect step definition to execute.  Use with caution!

Answer (score 0):

It's your (.*) regex. That can mean nothing at all. I use "([^"]*)" and wrap my adjective (color, in this case) in quotes. Or you could use (.+) which requires at least one character to match, and should disambiguate.

```
And I look for an apple in "yellow" basket with the following items
```

and

```
@When("^I look for an? (apple|pear|grape) in "([^"]*)" basket with the following items:$"
```

BTW, not asked about but you are missing your article for the basket. As a software tester, that 'bugs' me ;-)

```
@When("^I look for an? (apple|pear|grape) in an? "([^"]*)" basket with the following items:$"
```